# Discrete-Time Stochastic Calculus and Stopping Times: Resources

Tags: self-learning, martingales, markov-process

In my measure-theoretic probability course we covered what the professor called "discrete-time stochastic calculus". Essentially, it was a three part method for computing certain quantities such as expectations of hitting times, optimal stopping times, and certain related probabilities. The process was:

1. Find a (sub/super)martingale that yields the appropriate value when
   stopped.
2. Find a Markov process that will give us a difference equation with boundary values/initial values.
3. Solve the difference equation to ultimately get the quantity of interest.

I'm looking for a good book that covers this method or methods like this. What area of stochastic analysis does this fall under? Where can I get a resource with good practice problems?

Comment: What kind of stochastic processes are interested in? Markov processes? You can have a look into first and second "Course in Stochastic Processes" of Karlin and Taylor. The books cover a variety of material, where the first concentrates on discrete time processes.

Comment: Mainly interested in random walks for the relevant Markov process but also maybe discrete time Markov chains in general. I know we'll cover a lot of this stuff in continuous time in my stochastic analysis course.